# Return entry where matrix field is not empty

Tags: entries, matrix

I am trying to get a random entry which has the `quote` matrix field populated.

I've tried this:

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('entries').quote(':notempty:').order('RAND()').limit(1) %}
```

That isn't working. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently the only way to find entries that have Matrix rows is with the `search` param:

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('entries').search('quote:*').order('RAND()').limit(1) %}
```

Comment: is this true for craft 3 as well?